# How to parse data in Qt C++ without use of json?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource) Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 4.9.1, 32 bit) on Ubuntu 14.04 and developing app for embedded linux device. In my app I get some currency in every 30 second. So, In my main window I set the QThread and QTimer and using QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkRequest I get the below data.  Now I have a 6 label on my main window such as;

lblBuy_USD, lblBuy_EUR, lblBuy_STG, lblSale_USD, lblSale_EUR, lblSale_STG

My problem is I cannot use json file in my Qt. So, my question is that how can extract dollar-sale-data (which is 3,9500) from the data that I get from QNetworkRequest?

```
{
    "date": "20171108",
    "currencies": {

        "dollar": {
            "buy": "3,8450",
            "sale": "3,9500",
            "e_buy": "3,8450"
        },

        "sterling": {
            " buy ": "5,0500",
            " sale ": "5,1700",
            " e_buy ": "5,0500"
        },

        "euro": {
            " buy ": "4,4600",
            " sale ": "4,5650",
            " e_buy ": "4,4600"
        }

      }
}
```

UPDATE:
I use regular expressions but I couldn't get any data. My label has no value. Any help please?

```
       QString strReply = (QString)currentReply->readAll();

        QRegExp rxBUY_USD("dollar.*?buy.*?(\\d+\\,\\d+)"); 
         if( rxBUY_USD.indexIn( strReply ) != -1 )
         {
             ui->lblBUY_USD->setText( rxBUY_USD.cap( 1 ));
         }
```

Comment: put it into a string and parse it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use JSON? This network response *is* JSON, so you are using it whether you want to or not. If you can't use a specific JSON library, use a different one.

Comment: It sounds strange that you cannot use Qt Json classes (like QJsonDocument) they are in QtCore..

Comment: You could use regular expressions to isolate the `"dollar": ... },` part, and from it, isolate the `"sale": ...", part and finally get the value.

Comment: Thank you, my version of Qt don't have QJsonDocument otherwise I will use it. @dtech can you give me example of how to isolate the dollar using regular expressions?

Comment: What qt version are you using because Qt has json since 5.0

Comment: my Qt version is in my post. @vahancho suggestion works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get Dollar sales you can try to do the following:

```
QRegularExpression re("dollar.*?sale.*?(\\d+\\,\\d+)"); // Watch the decimal separator
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(s); // s - is the JSON string you got
if (match.hasMatch())
{
  QString matched = match.captured(1);     
  // Convert string to number, if needed.
}
else
{
  // Failed to find dollar sales
}
```

**UPDATE**

The same can be achieved by using `QRegExp` classes (old):

```
QRegExp re2("dollar.*sale.*(\\d+\\,\\d+).*");
if (re2.indexIn(s) != -1)
{
  QString matched = re2.cap(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vahancho. I update my post. I couldn't get any value. Plus I couldn't use QRegularExpressionMatch I have .indexIn that act like match.

Comment: I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @vahancho. It works perfectly with your update.